# How can I write reusable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, code-reuse

I've started to wrap my functions inside of Objects, e.g.:

```
var Search = {
  carSearch: function(color) {
  },
  peopleSearch: function(name) {
  },
  ...
}
```

This helps a lot with *readability*, but I continue to have issues with *reusabilty*.  To be more specific, the difficulty is in two areas:

1. **Receiving parameters**.  A lot of times I will have a search screen with multiple input fields and a button that calls the javascript search function.  I have to either put a bunch of code in the onclick of the button to retrieve and then martial the values from the input fields into the function call, or I have to hardcode the HTML input field names/IDs so that I can subsequently retrieve them with Javascript.  The solution I've settled on for this is to pass the field names/IDs into the function, which it then uses to retrieve the values from the input fields.  This is simple but really seems improper.
2. **Returning values**.  The effect of most Javascript calls tends to be one in which some visual on the screen changes directly, or as a result of another action performed in the call.  Reusability is toast when I put these screen-altering effects at the end of a function.  For example, after a search is completed I need to display the results on the screen.

How do others handle these issues?  Putting my thinking cap on leads me to believe that I need to have an page-specific layer of Javascript between each use in my application and the generic methods I create which are to be used application-wide.  Using the previous example, I would have a search button whose onclick calls a myPageSpecificSearchFunction, in which the search field IDs/names are hardcoded, which marshals the parameters and calls the generic search function.  The generic function would return data/objects/variables only, and would not directly read from or make any changes to the DOM.  The page-specific search function would then receive this data back and alter the DOM appropriately.

Am I on the right path or is there a better pattern to handle the reuse of Javascript objects/methods?

Comment: Recommend making this a community wiki, it's pretty subjective.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Basic Pattern

In terms of your basic pattern, can I suggest modifying your structure to use the module pattern and named functions:

```
var Search = (function(){
    var pubs = {};

    pubs.carSearch = carSearch;
    function carSearch(color) {
    }

    pubs.peopleSearch = peopleSearch;
    function peopleSearch(name) {
    }

    return pubs;
})();
```

Yes, that looks more complicated, but that's partially because there's no helper function involved. Note that now, every function has a name (your previous functions were anonymous; the properties they were bound to had names, but the functions didn't, which has implications in terms of the display of the call stack in debuggers and such). Using the module pattern also gives you the ability to have completely private functions that only the functions within your `Search` object can access. (Just declare the functions within the big anonymous function and don't add them to `pubs`.) More on my rationale for that (with advantages and disadvantages, and why you can't combine the function declaration and property assignment) [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).

#### Retrieving Parameters

One of the functions I really, really like from [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) is the [`Form#serialize`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/serialize/) function, which walks through the form elements and builds a plain object with a property for each field based on the field's name. (Prototype's current – 1.6.1 – implementation has an issue where it doesn't preserve the *order* of the fields, but it's surprising how rarely that's a problem.) It sounds like you would be well-served by such a thing and they're not hard to build; then your business logic is dealing with objects with properties named according to what they're related to, and has no knowledge of the actual form itself.

#### Returning Values / Mixing UI and Logic

I tend to think of applications as objects and the connections and interactions between them. So I tend to create:

- Objects representing the business model and such, irrespective of interface (although, of course, the *business model* is almost certainly partially driven by the interface). Those objects are defined in one place, but used both client- and server-side (yes, I use JavaScript server-side), and designed with serialization (via JSON, in my case) in mind so I can send them back and forth easily.
- Objects server-side that know how to use those to update the underlying store (since I tend to work on projects with an underlying store), and
- Objects client-side that know how to use that information to render to the UI.

(I know, hardly original!) I try to keep the store and rendering objects generic so they mostly work by looking at the public properties of the business objects (which is pretty much all of the properties; I don't use the patterns like Crockford's that let you really hide data, I find them too expensive). Pragmatism means sometimes the store or rendering objects just have to know what they're dealing with, specifically, but I do try to keep things generic where I can.

Comment: Very interesting stuff.  I'm not sure how feasible the server-side javascript is going to be for me (can you share with us the technologies you use for this?), but I'll be looking into the module pattern and Prototype method you mentioned.

Comment: @Renderln: (Weird, I replied earlier but it's gone.) Right now a lot of my app work is on intranets using IIS because of the platform the app runs on, and so there I just use JScript (sometimes JScript.Net, but mostly just JScript). In some of my other work I use Rhino on top of a Java stack (Rhino being JS for the JVM). But there are other options, such as Google's freaky-fast V8 interpreter/compiler (the one they use in Chrome), which is available as an Apache module  from at least one and I *think* two projects. SpiderMonkey is used server-side by CouchDB and others. You get the idea. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have a question about that kind of design. I'm actually thinking in classes and how to manage those in a reusable way. Are you able to create several objects belonging to the same "class" with that pattern?

Comment: @kitimenpolku: I don't think I'd use that pattern above for that. [Here's a page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) showing a robust pattern for creating "classes." It's in the context of comparing doing it both with and without my helper script [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs), but you don't need to use the script (though you're welcome to), the comparison page shows you to do it without.

Comment: This is old, but I can't get your example code to work as-is; I have to change `var pubs;` to `var pubs = {};` or I get an *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'carSearch' of undefined."* error.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: Thanks, `var pubs;` should have been `var pubs = {};` Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is ridiculously flexible which means that your design is especially important as you can do things in many different ways. This is what probably makes Javascript feel less like lending itself to re-usability.

There are a few different notations for declaring your objects (functions/classes) and then namespacing them. It's important to understand these differences. As mentioned in a comment on here 'namespacing is a breeze' - and is a good place to start.

I wouldn't be able to go far enough in this reply and would only be paraphrasing, so I recommend buying these books:

[Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](http://apress.com/book/view/159059908x)

[Pro Javascript techniques](http://apress.com/book/view/1590597273)

Answer (score 1):

I started out using the [module pattern](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/07/24/show-love-to-the-module-pattern/), but then started doing everything in [jQuery plugins](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern). The plugins allow to pass page specific options.

Using jQuery would also let you rethink the way you identify your search terms and find their values. You might consider adding a class to every input, and use that class to avoid specifically naming each input.